# TFS Create Work item not found system field

Tags: c#, tfs

1. How to create types "`Epic`", "`Features`"?

   [image]

```
public static void CreateWorkItems()
            {
                TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/Agile_collection/"));
                var workItemStore = tpc.GetService();
                var teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["Test_WI"];
                var workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Task"];
                var userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
                {
                    Title = "Title",
                    Description =
                        "Description"
                };
                // Save the new user story. 
                userStory.Save();
                Console.WriteLine(@"WorkItem id: " + userStory.Id);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

2. How could not find additional fields when creating workItem field **Related work** add Parent or Child?

[image]

```
public static void UpdateWorkItems()
{
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/Agile_collection/"));
    WorkItemStore wis = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    WorkItem item = wis.GetWorkItem(1);
    //Related work
    item.Fields["IterationPath"].Value = 50;
    item.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example how to create work items (Feature and User Story):

```
 WorkItemStore wistore = new WorkItemStore("<your_tfs_url>");
 string TeamProjectName = "TestProject";
 string UST = "User Story";
 string FTT = "Feature";

 WorkItem userStory = wistore.Projects[TeamProjectName].WorkItemTypes[UST].NewWorkItem();

 userStory.Title = "User Story From C# Project";
 userStory.Save();

 WorkItem feature = wistore.Projects[TeamProjectName].WorkItemTypes[FTT].NewWorkItem();

 feature.Title = "Feature From C# Project";
 feature.Save();
```

This is the example ho to create linked work items and add completed hours

```
WorkItemStore wistore = new WorkItemStore("<your_tfs_url>");
WorkItemLinkTypeEnd childLinkType = wistore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward"];
string CopmletedWorkFieldName = "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork";
string TeamProjectName = "TestProject";
string TSK = "Task";
string FTT = "Feature";

WorkItem task = wistore.Projects[TeamProjectName].WorkItemTypes[TSK].NewWorkItem();

task.Title = "Task From C# Project";
task.Save();

WorkItem feature = wistore.Projects[TeamProjectName].WorkItemTypes[FTT].NewWorkItem();

feature.Title = "Feature From C# Project";
feature.WorkItemLinks.Add(new WorkItemLink(childLinkType, task.Id));
feature.Save();

task.Fields[CopmletedWorkFieldName].Value = 10;
task.Save();
```

Here is additional links:

1. [Link type reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)
2. [Fields used to estimate and track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#fields-used-to-estimate-and-track-work)

Comment: Aleksander how to save Assigned To is blank? feature.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = ""; not working?